# View more posts of a sub-category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, get-posts

Here's what I'm trying to do-

Suppose the visitor is on a page that's a subcategory. I want add a custom text on the top or bottom of the post that is a link which shows more posts from that same subcategory the visitor is on right now. So if the subcategory was 'Ice-cream' I would like to place a link that would say 'view more from 'ice cream'. Hopefully it makes sense.

I've just started working with Wordpress. So any advice/suggestion would be much appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to use [the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)

Displays a link to the category or categories a post belongs to. This tag must be used within The Loop.